# Dealing with erronous data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I am calculating z scores for cross-sectional time series data in Matlab, using the following code

```
bond_price = double(bond);
 for i = 1+period : noofdates
    zscores(i-period,:) = (bond_price(i,:) - mean(bond_price(i-period:i-1,:)))./std(bond_price(i-period:i-1,:));
end
```

I am using period = 60 
But the problem is I don't want to calculate the z-score if data for the security has less than 60 data points. Can I use a function in Matlab which will take care of this within the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
bond_price = double(bond);
for i = 1+period : noofdates
    if size(bond_price,1) >= 60
        zscores(i-period,:) = (bond_price(i,:) - mean(bond_price(i-period:i-1,:)))./std(bond_price(i-period:i-1,:));
    end    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `if` statement within your loop that will check the validity of your data. For example

```
bond_price_tmp = bond_price(i-period:i-1,:);

if sum(isnan(bond_price_tmp)) > 0   %if your missing data is NaN 
    zscores(i-period,:) = NaN;
else
    zscores(i-period,:) = (bond_price(i,:) ...
end
```

or

```
if sum(bond_price_tmp==0) > 0       %if your missing data is 0
    zscores(i-period,:) = 0;
else
    zscores(i-period,:) = (bond_price(i,:) ...
end
```